# Low rank approximation of a big sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am trying to approximate a big matrix with a lower rank matrix.

I have matrix `mat_to_use` for which each column represents something like bag of words for a file; the matrix itself is represented as a scipy sparse matrix. I want to use this matrix to serach for context in files.

The problem Is, basic searching yields a lot noise. For that reason, I picked SVD to remove it.

This is how I do it:

```
U, E, VT = scipy.sparse.linalg.svds(mat_to_use.T, 100)
S = np.diag(E)
r = scipy.sparse.csc_matrix(U @ S @ VT)
```

Just to note - bag of words of file *i* is stored in column *i* of the matrix, while rows represent word indices. This is why I transpose the matrix for the SVD.

But there is a problem. I have over 2000 files with raw HDD size of over 1.4GB.
The `mat_to_use` matrix is sparse, but the `VT` matrix is by any means not.
While the `mat_to_use` takes about 500MB to store, the matrix multiplication process takes more than 20GB of ram to complete, making it impossible for me to calculate.

Would there be any better solution to tackle this problem? The SVD decomposition itself doesn't take long, and the memory usage is plausible, but the matrix multiplication step is something I cannot accept, as I feel there must be a better solution for this - maybe there is a way to approximate a lower-rank matrix in place?

Comment: Sparse or truncated SVD?

Comment: @CJR That's pretty much what scipy.linalg.svds does, the problem is SVD eigenvectors are not sparse, so multiplying UEV.T yields a non-sparse matrix as well which takes up a lot of space.

Comment: Well the nature of what you're trying to do is that the largest components *wont* give you a sparse matrix. You could solve it as a regression problem instead and it might make a dent in your memory usage.